# Kotlin DSL list of String

Tags: string, list, kotlin, dsl

I am trying to have a DSL which will create a list of Strings e.g.

```
Person {
  name = "Test"
  subjects {
      "Physics"
      "Chemistry"
      "Maths"
   }
}
```

Not sure how I can do this to get the list of subjects which will be stored as a list and calls an api internally.

Comment: Not possible with this syntax. Have you considered `subjects("Physics", "Chemistry", "Maths")` instead?

Comment: was thinking the { } with the comma should be ok
 subjects {
"checm",
"Maths",
"Bio"
}

Comment: Some existing libraries use `unaryPlus()` operator for this purpose. It looks like this: `subjects { +"Physics" \n +"Chemistry" }`. However, this is error-prone and I believe `kotlinx-serialization` already deprecated this (or maybe it was some other lib?). Remember that we can have any possible Kotlin code inside `{}` - loops, ifs, etc. It is really hard to read if some string in the middle of the code have a hidden behavior. Also, DSLs are one of the most advanced and hardest to understand features in Kotlin. They aren't that good for beginners.

Comment: Also, `select()` from coroutines uses `invoke` operator for similar purposes. So it would be: `subjects { "Physics"() \n "Chemistry"() }`.

Comment: Try this to show list of strings- val list = listOf("a", "b", "c")
for more details go with the -https://kotlinlang.org/docs/idioms.html

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at [`buildList`-documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/build-list.html) or [`buildList`-source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/aaef41cf64458a0c55a008162dc770f9778b2442/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Collections.kt#L172) / [JVM-actual-functions](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/aaef41cf64458a0c55a008162dc770f9778b2442/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/collections/CollectionsJVM.kt)...